# Sublime Editor 2: Key-bindings to send command to terminal

Tags: python, r, sublimetext2, r-markdown, sublime-text-plugin

I'm very new to Sublime and advanced text editors to be honest and any help/straightening up would be appreciated.

I'd like to set up a key-binding in Sublime Editor 2 that executes a command in Terminal inserting the current file name.

Specifically, I'd like to execute an Rscript that will render the markdown I am working on, i.e. Execute the following file in Terminal (replacing *FILE* with the filename Sublime is focused on).

```
Rscript -e "library(rmarkdown);render(*FILE*, "pdf_document")"
```

I've found a subprocess call that should send a command like this to Terminal.app, but I don't know how to integrate it with Sublime

```
subprocess.call(['osascript', '-e', 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "Rscript -e "library(rmarkdown);render(*FILE*, "pdf_document")" in window 1'])
```

Any help or advice would me much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend checking out the [`R-Box`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/R-Box) plugin from [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io) for working with R. Like many packages, most of the active development work is occurring on the Sublime Text 3 version, so unless there is a really compelling reason to stay with ST2 I **strongly** suggest you [upgrade](http://www.sublimetext.com/3). There are quite a few reasons to upgrade, which I won't get into here, but suffice it to say that ST3 is fast, stable, and perfectly useable for anyone, and most of all for this particular situations, contains many behind-the-scenes enhancements allowing plugins to do more than ever before.